# Current Post ID is not fetching in function.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch the current post id in function.php file for some reason.

I have used the below code :

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo $postid;
?>
```

But not getting any thing...

Comment: Is that your full functions.php file?

Comment: yes, it's wordpress default function.php file

Answer (score 5):

The post ID isn't available to you right when **functions.php** runs. You'll need to hook into [`'template_redirect'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) (or later):

```
function get_current_post_ID() {
    $postid = get_queried_object_id();
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_current_post_ID' );
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another word press hook 'wp' which return current post ID in function.php

```
function mypostID()
{
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();      
}
add_action('wp','mypostID');
```